z score total for fixed alpha and beta in sample size calculation of mean differences
Can someone explain in detail how $z_\text{total}=z_{\alpha} + z_{1-\beta}$ in a one-tailed hypothesis test of mean difference $\mu_1 - \mu_2$ with common variance in order to determine sample size.
All references I have found arrive at this formula but do not break down the steps involved at arriving there.

Recall that the test statistic here is $\frac{\Delta}{\text{SE}}$, with $\Delta=\mu_1-\mu_2$, $\text{SE}=\sqrt{(1/n_1+1/n_2)\ \sigma^2}$, and $\sigma$ considered known. This statistic follows a standard normal distribution under the null. The power for your one-sided (upper) test is then the probability that this result is more extreme than the $1-\alpha$ critical value:
$$
P(Z>\frac{\Delta}{\text{SE}}-z_{1-\alpha})
$$
You can calculate this probability using the standard normal CDF. To determine sample size you want to fix the power at some level $1-\beta$ and solve for $n$. The key part here is that the right-hand side of the above inequality needs to be equal to $z_{1-\beta}$ (by taking the inverse normal CDF of each side):
$$
\begin{align}
P(Z>\frac{\Delta}{\text{SE}}-z_{1-\alpha}) = 1-\beta\ &\Longleftrightarrow\ 1-P(Z<\frac{\Delta}{\text{SE}}-z_{1-\alpha})=1-\beta \\&\Longleftrightarrow\ 
\frac{\Delta}{\text{SE}}-z_{1-\alpha} = z_{1-\beta}
\end{align}
$$
We usually assume balanced sample size, also because this is the most powerful comparison. Taking $n=n_1=n_2$, rearranging using $\frac{\Delta}{\text{SE}}=\frac{\Delta}{\sigma}\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}$, and further abbreviating the effect size $\frac{\Delta}{\sigma}=\text{d}$ gives:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{d}\ \sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}-z_{1-\alpha}&=z_{1-\beta} \\
\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}&=\frac{z_{1-\beta}+z_{1-\alpha}}{\text{d}} \\
n&=2\Big(\frac{z_{1-\beta}+z_{1-\alpha}}{\text{d}}\Big)^2
\end{align}
$$
This can be further rearranged using symmetries like $z_\alpha=-z_{1-\alpha}$, the way in which the standard normal quantiles enter the equation should hopefully be clear though.
